# If somebody choose a value from choice field in NewForm, then pop-up window or notification is displayed

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, list-form, classic-experience

Is it possible in SharePoint (I use Classic Experience) to display a notification, when somebody choose particular value from choice field in New Form?

For example, I've a choice field in New Form, called "Country" - there is a list of values to choose USA, Europe, Asia.

If someone choose "Asia" then SharePoint display a pop-up or any notification windows about the content "Country is chosen".

Is it possible with a little coding in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Country` choice field as a dropdown, try adding below code to your `NewForm.aspx` using **Content Editor** or **Script Editor** web part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    
        //Show alert based on "Country" column 
        $("select[title^='Country']").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "Asia") {
                alert("Asia is chosen");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh :) It's working, generally, i have to rebuild one script, because if I implement yours script, then other doesn't work.

Comment: If you have another script on same page, you can merge those as per your requirements.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

Ganesh, script which doesn't work after implement yours is based on SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns.

Here's a section of it:

$(document).ready(function() {
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
relationshipList: "Profity",
relationshipListParentColumn: "Region",
relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
parentColumn: "Zmiana Profitu",
childColumn: "Country",
debug: true
});
})

childColumn, has values: USA, Europe and Asia, and there, if i choose "Asia", i'm expecting an alert "Asia is chosen". How to marry this two scripts?